# animall animations dont work with logic in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to create a game in which an object defoms: a tube is blown up. To create the animation I use the Animall add-on because it allows to set keyframes on the position of edges en vertices in edit mode. When I run the animation with the forward button or move the time line, it is perfect.

However, when I define an action brick to run that animation, it does not work!
Changing position or rotation is no problem with the logic but deformation doesnt seem to work! Of course I also tried with a super simple deformation, moving only one edge or vertex. Same problem.
Is this a known problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have not used animall, but I do know that shapekeys (which can do the same thing) work in BGE

Comment: Simple question: Does the AnimAll add-on support the BGE? Might want to check the documentation.